# Compiled Symfony container php syntax

Tags: php, symfony

After Symfony compiles the container and dumps it into cache folder it provides us with a class with tons of functions that represent services.

I never saw this syntax before and wonder what that particular lambda function actually returns:

```
protected function getDebug_EventDispatcherService()
{
     // ...

     $instance->addListener('kernel.controller', array(0 => function () {
            return ${($_ = isset($this->services['data_collector.router']) ? $this->services['data_collector.router'] : $this->get('data_collector.router')) && false ?: '_'};
     }
     // ...
     );

     return $instance;
}
```

**First**: What is this syntax `return ${...}` and how it works? I know this is called [Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), but here it's not part of a string, am I right?

**Second**: logical expression within curly braces is basically the following `${(//...) && false ?: '_'}`. Why do we need that `false` over there?

Please explain what I'm missing here.

Comment: the 1st part is a variable variable http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php not quite sure about the expression evaluation yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

different parts:

```
${ 'stringvalue' }
```

is essentially the same as

```
$stringvalue
```

then

```
($_ = [expression] && false ?: '_')
```

is essentially (since whatever the expression is, the statment left of `?:` returns false, so the right side is returned):

```
$_ = [expression];
return '_'; // only, it doesn't really return
```

and last but not least for `[expression]`

```
isset($this->services['data_collector.router']) 
  ? $this->services['data_collector.router'] 
  : $this->get('data_collector.router')
```

is:

```
if(isset($this->services['data_collector.router'])) {
     return $this->services['data_collector.router'];
} else {
     return $this->get('data_collector.router');
}
```

now, to put the parts together:

the router service (`'data_collector.router'`) is retrieved (either created or the stored reference is used), it is assigned to `$_`. Then the `&& false ?: '_'` returns the name of the var: `_`, which turns the outermost expression into:

```
// $_ was just given a value
return $_;
```

so overall the code is *somewhat* equivalent to:

```
if(isset($this->services['data_collector.router'])) {
    $_ = $this->services['data_collector.router'];
} else {
    $_ = $this->get('data_collector.router');
}
return $_;
```

hope this helps ;o)

Comment: great explanation, thank you! but why don't just use `return isset($this->services['data_collector.router']) ? $this->services['data_collector.router'] : $this->get('data_collector.router'))`?

Comment: @starnzd I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It's a variable variable name.

[Php variables](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.php)

You can define at runtime the name of the variables (not only the value)